No 5GHz band on BCM43224
I'm quite new to Linux. When I was booting from live USB for Ubuntu Desktop installation(latest version), the 5GHz band was present, so I am sure that it can work. I ticked Install proprietary drivers during the installation procedure. After booting to the installed Ubuntu, I can't connect to 5GHz network, only 2.4 GHz. So may be it's proprietary driver? What are possible solution steps?

Delete proprietary driver (make default Linux drivers work)?
Install other driver?

Update:
After updating Ubuntu to 24.10 it can't find drivers for my network card anymore in Additional Drivers app.
Update 2:
After comparing sudo apt list --installed from "installed" and "live cd" version i found out that wireless-tools is missing somehow... In apt list on "installed" version it is said residual-config so that means it was installed. Installed it back, but that didn`t help ...
My Hardware is: MacBook Air 2012, BCM43224 - network card.
My Software is: FW version 264.0.0.0.0 ; Os Ubuntu 24.10 ; Kernel version 6.11.0-9-generic

I got it working ! So what i did was: run lsmod on live boot cd and compared it to my system. The main difference was that there was no b43 installed and instead it was wl installed on my local system. I removed wl using modprobe -r wl and installed b43 sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer. But that wasn`t enough because wl created blacklist files in  /etc/modprobe.d . So i removed this files (compared it with this folder on live cd). It works fine now!
